# Adding a default HTTP header in Go

Tags: http, go, authorization

I'm taking my first steps in Go and would like to consume a REST API. The server requires each request to be authorized with a bearer token.

How can I add this header to the client so that every request uses this token?

```
import "net/http"

const accessToken = "MY_DEMO_TOKEN"

func main() {
    customHeader := http.Header{}
    customHeader.Add("Authorization: Bearer %s", accessToken)
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: time.Second*10,
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can, because request headers aren't a property of the client, they're a property of the request. You could write a simple helper function to prepare requests with the appropriate header, though.

Answer (score 20):

You can decorate the client's Transport. For instance:

```
package main

import "net/http"

func main() {
    client := http.DefaultClient

    rt := WithHeader(client.Transport)
    rt.Set("Authorization", "Bearer <token>")
    client.Transport = rt

    client.Get("http://example.com")
}

type withHeader struct {
    http.Header
    rt http.RoundTripper
}

func WithHeader(rt http.RoundTripper) withHeader {
    if rt == nil {
        rt = http.DefaultTransport
    }

    return withHeader{Header: make(http.Header), rt: rt}
}

func (h withHeader) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    if len(h.Header) == 0 {
        return h.rt.RoundTrip(req)
    }

    req = req.Clone(req.Context())
    for k, v := range h.Header {
        req.Header[k] = v
    }

    return h.rt.RoundTrip(req)
}
```

For the specific purpose of authorization tokens, you might be interested in the [golang.org/x/oauth2](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/oauth2) package, which does essentially the same, but also supports automatic token renewal:

```
package main

import (
    "context"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client := oauth2.NewClient(ctx, oauth2.StaticTokenSource(&oauth2.Token{
        AccessToken: "<your token>",
        TokenType:   "Bearer",
    }))

    client.Get("http://example.com")
}
```

Comment: 3 years in the future this worked for me, gotta love Go. Thanks!

Comment: Please don't do this. The [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#RoundTripper) for `http.RoundTripper` says: "RoundTrip should not modify the request, except for consuming and closing the Request's Body." It works now, but it's not a good idea to do something the documentation says not to do because it may lead to future confusion or breakage.

Comment: I think this answer predates that restriction. It definitely predates the addition of Request.Clone. In any case, I've updated the answer. Thanks for pointing that out, @MosheKatz.

Comment: The [commit](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/b9ad2787dd6ada95c0712072079146cd2f586d7c) that introduced this restriction was made in October 2011, so it predates this answer by almost 7 years, but it's not a big deal. It's just something to be aware of. I'm sure that there are hundreds (maybe thousands) of places where people have done things like this, and most of them probably work fine. I only just discovered the documentation myself despite how long it's been there.

Answer (score 6):

You can write a decorator around http.RoundTripper and pass it to the client. But practically I would end up with a helper that prepares request for each query as was suggested by Adrian.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

const accessToken = "MY_DEMO_TOKEN"

type MyRoundTripper struct {
    r http.RoundTripper
}

func (mrt MyRoundTripper) RoundTrip(r *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    r.Header.Add("Authorization", "Bearer: "+accessToken)
    return mrt.r.RoundTrip(r)
}

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout:   time.Second * 10,
        Transport: MyRoundTripper{r: http.DefaultTransport},
    }

    fmt.Println(client.Get("http://google.com/"))
}
```